# Basic difference between drupal_goto() and drupal_render()

Tags: drupal-7

I want to know basic main difference between drupal_goto() and drupal_render()

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid there are only differencies because these 2 functions are different in every points. They are not meant to be for the same thing at all. If you want, I'll develop in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are 2 (very) different drupal functions.

[drupal_goto()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) **redirects** users to a different page. It is the equivalent of the php `header('Location: http://www.example.com/')`.

[drupal_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) **transforms** an associative array tree to HTML automatically (to display the page the users will see).

For more information about these functions, please refer to the documentation.